# obtaining the value in GTK fortran entry for real number

Tags: c, fortran, gtk

I am having an array of real items that I would like to add as entry in GTK fortran. The values are showing fine, but when I am trying to get the number from the buffer in the entry, it would only give me the first character in that real number. I have tried setting the len of the character, but it would crash.
The code are follows:

the entry:

```
write(test,"(f0.4)") param_initValue(i)
scrollWid_initEntry(i) = gtk_entry_new_with_buffer(gtk_entry_buffer_new(test,-1))
call gtk_container_add(scrollWid_container(i), scrollWid_initEntry(i))
call g_signal_connect(scrollWid_initEntry(i), 'activate' // c_null_char, c_funloc(onChangeInit),c_loc(param_labelName(I)))
```

the function called when activate:

```
 subroutine onChangeInit(widget,datas)
    use GUI_botParam_paramValueData
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_ptr, c_int,c_f_pointer,c_char
    use gtk_sup, only: c_f_string_copy
    use :: gtk, only:  gtk_entry_get_buffer,gtk_entry_buffer_get_text,gtk_entry_buffer_get_length 
    implicit none
    type(c_ptr) :: widget,charac_newEntry
    character(len=20):: datas
    character(len=:),allocatable :: newEntry
    integer :: index,n,number
    do n=1,numberOfParam
        if (param_labelName(n) == datas) index = n
    end do
    charac_newEntry = gtk_entry_get_buffer(scrollWid_initEntry(index))
    call c_f_string_copy(gtk_entry_buffer_get_text(charac_newEntry),newEntry)
    
end
```

EDIT#1 Solution 1
function rewritten to

```
subroutine onChangeInit(widget,datas)
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_ptr, c_int,c_f_pointer,c_char
    use gtk_sup, only: c_f_string_copy
    use :: gtk, only:  gtk_entry_get_buffer,gtk_entry_buffer_get_text,gtk_entry_buffer_get_length,gtk_entry_get_text 
    implicit none
    type(c_ptr),value :: widget
    type(c_ptr) :: charac_newEntry
    character(len=20):: datas
    character(len=20):: newEntry
    integer :: index,n,number
    do n=1,numberOfBaseParam
        if (baseParam_labelName(n) == datas) index = n
    end do
    print*, index
    ! charac_newEntry = gtk_entry_get_buffer(base_scrollWid_initEntry(index))
    call c_f_string_copy(gtk_entry_get_text(base_scrollWid_initEntry(index)),newEntry)
    print*, trim(newEntry)
    
end subroutine onChangeInit
```

Basically used "gtk_entry_get_text" to get the text, with the converted fortran character set to len=20

Comment: you likely have an issue in `c_f_string_copy`: how do you query the lenght of the C string? You should loop over the C pointer elements until you find a `c_null_char`

Comment: @FedericoPerini thank you for the reply! I obtain the buffer with the string using gtk_entry_get_buffer then get the actual c string with gtk_entry_buffer_get_text. From https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.EntryBuffer.get_text.html , I think it only returns a c char, as I am not that familiar with C, I am not sure how do you actually query it. I would be great if you can give me a demonstration

Comment: To everyone, I have fixed the issue, somehow using base_scrollWid_initEntry with the newEntry allocated to character with len =20 worked as showed in the new edit. Thank you for everyone!